# Can't Build with firebase-config:16.0.0 and firebase-core:16.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

When I build with the [latest released versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of `firebase-config` and `firebase-core`, I get this error:

> The library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base` is
>   being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4],
>   [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using `./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

How can I resolve this dependency conflict?

My project gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app module gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 201
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I am facing the same error and even with your solution I am still getting the warning, What can I do? Thanks

Comment: @Spirrow: Make sure you are using the latest versions of other Firebase libs.  In particular, the same error will occur if `firebase-invites:16.0.0` is used instead of 16.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, the error does not occur when `firebase-core` is placed before other Firebase libs in the dependencies list:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was absolutely maddening before finding this. Thanks!

Comment: I spent two days for this error......rolled back and updated again......fresh installlation......n now I found this -_-

Answer (score 0):

yesterday, i was face same problem .it is easily solved by following dependencies.include these two in your app gradle and sync your project.

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

Comment: When I make these changes to the posted `build.gradle` file, I get the same error.