# Gradle sync failure after Firebase update

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

From yesterday ( 2018/08/14 ) i can't build our project without any change ( 2 days ago it was works fine ) because of this error :

```
Failed to resolve: play-services-auth-base
```

So i searched for this and some solutions found that said update firebase dependencies and something like this.
We updated all of google dependencies but still get error.
here is my gradle google dependencies :

```
//moudule level gradle

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

//project level build.gradle

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

After update to this :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

I got this error :

```
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

Google Updated Firebase :
[Firebase Android Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180813)

What is the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried to change `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'` and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Try moving `firebase-core` to place it above the other firebase libs in the dependencies list.  See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025793/4815718

Comment: please add all your dependencies. you have to remove this line: (implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'). it exists in other dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case there is conflict with firebase versions and oneSignal library:
set version of oneSignal from 0.8.1 to 0.11.2 fix my problem.

These are firebase dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Thats it!

Below Solution works fine too!

Set version of dependencies to 11.8.0 like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
```

Then remove/comment this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth ...
```

I found that there is conflict in these dependencies because of : Transitive Dependencies.

Comment: with downgrade it's ok. but i need higher version :)

Answer (score 0):

step:1
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin

step:2

allprojects repositories

```
    google() // Google's Maven repository
```