# Another version conflict between Firebase and Play-Services: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

My app uses parts of Google Play Services and Firebase, and I want to implement Firebase's In-app Messaging. I have my `google-services` plugin at v4.1.0, and the related dependencies in my app-level Gradle file look like this:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1' //this error only popped up when I added this line
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1"
```

I got the following error while trying to build my app:

> `The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4], [16.0.2,16.0.2]], but resolves to 16.0.2.`

I know some other questions and Firebase's documentation that says I have to update all Firebase and Play Services' features to their latest versions, but these are the latest ones. I've checked in the official documentations of both.

16.0.2 only matches the `firebase-database` dependency, so is it something to do with that? Or is it something else (missing or in need of updates)?

EDIT: As requested, my project-level Gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            //url "https://jitpack.io"
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

And my `app` module-level Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.picmix.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "String", "EMBED", "\"\""

        versionCode 90      //Latest Version on Google Play
        versionName "7.7.8"

        packagingOptions{
            doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
            doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Volumes/work/cert/android/picmix_key")
            storePassword "P1cMIx_M0B1l3_#2012#"
            keyAlias "picmix"
            keyPassword "P1cMIx_M0B1l3_#2012#"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        dev2 {
            minSdkVersion 15
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        preload {
            buildConfigField "String", "EMBED", "\"huawei\""
        }

        prod {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }

        andgo {
            minSdkVersion 15
            versionCode 50000  + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
//        lintOptions {
//            checkReleaseBuilds false
//        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            //minifyEnabled true //Normally THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
            debuggable true
            //shrinkResources true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' //Normally THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    /*
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled true
    }
    */
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.1';
    gmsVersion = '15.0.0';
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/libadapterinmobi.jar')
//    implementation project(':volley')
    //debugimplementation project(path: ':PG_Edit_SDK', configuration: 'debug')
    //releaseimplementation project(path: ':PG_Edit_SDK', configuration: 'release')

    //implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.7.0@aar') {
    //    transitive = true;
    //}
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //implementation files('libs/InMobi-6.2.3.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/dagger-2.7.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-4.0.3.jar')
    //implementation(name: 'AudienceNetwork', ext: "aar")
    //implementation(name: 'PokktSDK_v6.0', ext: "aar")
    //implementation(name: 'unity-ads', ext: "aar")
    //implementation 'com.vmax.android.ads.aar:vmax@aar'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0'
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.5.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.8'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'

    implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.0.2'

    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try putting `firebase-core` first in the dependencie list as described in the answer to this related question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025793/4815718

Comment: I don't think it worked, though I did find that for some reason `com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0` together caused some sort of conflict - when I removed one of them, the error disappeared. How do I use the `:app:dependencies` option to see the conflicting stuff that caused the error?

Comment: To see the dependency tree, comment out the line at the bottom of your gradle file for `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` then in a terminal window enter the command `gradlew :app:dependencies`

Comment: I can't reproduce your results, although my configuration is different.  I'm using `google-services:4.0.2` and `gradle:3.3.0-alpha10`.  If you update your question to include your entire `build.gradle` files for both project and app module, I'll look at it more.

Comment: There's a `gradle:3.3.0-alpha10`? I thought the newest was 3.1.4.

Comment: I use the Canary builds of Android Studio.  3.3 Canary 10 uses `gradle:3.3.0-alpha10`

Comment: OK. Looks like changing my gradle plugin to v.3.3.0-alpha10 removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like a problem related to the plugin you are trying to add within firebase.

I tried to use play-services-vision with firebase-analytics and I was seeing the same error. Sometimes it gets stuck on version checks and it wont build if there is a newest version of the plugin (play-services-vision).

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2' // was 17.0.0
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

You can disable it if you want, but allways try to use the lattest version of your plugins.

Comment: By plugins, did you mean both the `play-services-vision` and `firebase-analytics` dependencies... and the Gradle plugin?